# Касательно вызова значения свойства объекта без ключа

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать JavaScript и столкнулся с вопросом, который не могу понять. Для примера возьмем console.log:

```
console.log()
```

Согласно информации, которую я нашел, *Console* - это объект, одним из свойств которого является *log* (ключ). В свою очередь значением свойства *log* является функция *log()*. Вопрос состоит в следующем: разве мы можем обращаться к значению свойства объекта, минуя сам ключ? Поискав в интернете, я заметил, что всегда обращаются к ключам объекта, однако в этом случае ситуация другая. Сам данный вопрос решить не могу, надеюсь на Вашу помощь. Спасибо!

Дополнение:

Спасибо всем за ответы. По информации, которую я нашел, "ключ" и "свойство" обозначают одно и то же, так и воспринял.
Я заметил, что некоторым не ясна суть вопроса, поэтому попытаюсь объяснить на примере такого рода:

```
let console = {
     log = log(),
     age = 1,
     color = 3
}
```

Чтобы получить значение в стандартных объектах, необходимо обратиться к свойству (то же самое, что и ключ):

```
let test = console.age
```

В таком случае мы получим спрятанное значение. Однако, чтобы выполнить функцию спрятанную в значении, мы разве можем обращаться к значению напрямую минуя ключ/свойство? На сколько это понял я, по логике должно выглядеть следующим образом:

```
console.log //Мы обращаемся к ключу, а не к значению log()
console.1 //Это прямое обращение к значению ключа age, однако это невозможно, хотя выражение console.log() именно обращается к значению, минуя ключ log
```

Надеюсь, я не запутал Вас еще больше)

Comment: ` разве мы можем обращаться к значению свойства объекта, минуя сам ключ?` переведи... Как это понять?

Comment: Вы что-то усложняете.  Метод `log` объекта `console` выводит сообщение в консоль браузера.  Вопрос _разве мы можем обращаться к значению свойства объекта, минуя сам ключ?_ непонятен.

Comment: _разве мы можем обращаться к значению свойства объекта, минуя сам ключ?_ - можно, `Object.values(console)` и будет массив функций, вызывать которые можно по индексу

Comment: @InDevX, в таком случае нужно еще узнать номер того индекса для своего ключа. :)

Comment: Тут кагбэ нужно определиться какое слово будет использоваться `свойство` или `ключ`. И что сам ТС вкладывает в их понятие... Что для него `свойство` и что `ключ`.

Comment: _console.1 //Это прямое обращение к значению ключа age, однако это невозможно, хотя выражение console.log() именно обращается к значению, минуя ключ log_ - это неверное утверждение.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь, буду разбираться дальше

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Наверное, вы думали, что сначала нужно получить значения свойства, а после вызывать функцию по имени:

```
console.log.log()
```

Так сделать не получится, потому что если обратиться к свойству `log` без круглых скобок `()` вы увидите, что внутри будет находится функция:

```
console.log // ƒ log() { [native code] }
```

Внутри `console.log` содержится готовая к выполнению функция. Для того чтобы она выполнилась, нужно добавить оператор вызова круглые скобоки `()`

Comment: Похоже, Вы поняли меня правильно, спасибо. Я постарался дополнить вопрос, насколько смог. Единственная вещь, которую я не понимаю такова: в случае, если в другом, допустим созданном мной объекте, в качестве значений одного из свойств будет функция, могу ли я как в примере с console.log() обратиться к значению? Скажем example.function(), что-то вроде этого.

Comment: К функции нужно обращаться по имени свойства объекта в котором она находится, например:
const myObject = { myFunction: function() { alert('Привет!') } }. Для вызова функции необходимо обратиться к myFunction: myObject.myFunction()

Comment: Кажется понял, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Рад был помочь, пожалуйста отметьте ответ принятым